# git auto merge on different lines

Tags: git, git-merge

I have a repo with the following structure:

```
master -> b -----\
   \----> a --\   \
    \----------v---v--> c
```

where branches `a`, `b` and `c` are based off of `master`, but `c` just contains a merge of both `a` and `b`.

In `master`, I have the following file (file.txt):

```
UNUSED_1
UNUSED_2
```

`a` modifies this file by writing

```
A
UNUSED_2
```

And `b` modifies this file by writing

```
UNUSED_1
B
```

When I try to merge `b` into `c` (after merging `a`) I get a merge conflict:

```
<<<<<<< HEAD
A
UNUSED_2
=======
UNUSED_1
B
>>>>>>> b
```

Is there a way to tell `git merge` that I want

```
A
B
```

in file.txt?

This is trivial to solve manually, but this is all done automatically in a script, where I have several "features", each represented by a branch, with the master branch "reserving" space for those features.

If I want a combination of features, I then create a new branch and merge all the required features to build.

*The following is a script to reliably re-create the situation described in the post up to the merge conflict:*

```sh
# Setup `master`
git init .
echo "UNUSED_1" >> "file.txt"
echo "UNUSED_2" >> "file.txt"
git add "file.txt"
git commit -m "Master commit"

# Setup `a`
git checkout -b "a"
rm "file.txt"
echo "A" >> "file.txt"
echo "UNUSED_2" >> "file.txt"
git add "file.txt"
git commit -m "A commit"

# Setup `b`
git checkout "master"
git checkout -b "b"
rm "file.txt"
echo "UNUSED_1" >> "file.txt"
echo "B" >> "file.txt"
git add "file.txt"
git commit -m "B commit"

# Try to merge in `c`
git checkout "master"
git checkout -b "c"
git merge --no-ff "a" -m "Merge A"
git merge --no-ff "b" -m "Merge B"
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to tell git merge that I want
>
> ```
> A
> B
> ```
>
> in file.txt?

No—but it's not `git merge` per se that you have to convince.  When `git merge` decides that a file *does* need a "true merge" because it is changed on "both sides" with respect to the merge base version, Git will pass this file to a *low level* merge driver.

Git has one built-in low-level merge driver, and the built-in one produces the conflict you see above.  But by defining a merge driver in your `.git/config` and then referring to that merge driver from `.gitattributes`, you can tell Git: *Use my merge driver instead of yours.*

Unfortunately, this means you must find or write a low level merge driver.

Fortunately, Git includes a separate program that is a low-level merge driver, called `git merge-file`.

Unfortunately, this program does the same thing by default (both it and the default low level merge use the same algorithm).

Fortunately, this program has *flags*.

Unfortunately, these flags are mostly the same as the existing `-X` flags, and the existing `-X` flags are insufficient.

Fortunately, `git merge-file` has one flag that the `-X` flags don't, namely `--union`.  The union merge operation means *take both sets of changes.*

Unfortunately, this operation is not tested on your particular case.

[Fortunately](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fortunately,_Unfortunately), you can test it.

(See also [frogurt](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Krbl911ZPBA).)

Comment: I've tested `--union` with `git merge-file --union "file_a.txt" "file_master.txt" "file_b.txt"` (where `file_{branch}.txt` means it's the file from that branch), but unfortunately it produces "A\nUNUSED_2\nUNUSED_1\nB\n", so it duplicates the lines. I'll look into the approach of writing a low level merge driver for my specific use case, though.

Comment: I'm not surprised, as "union merge" is often described as "keep both" but I think this really means "keep all additions, never take any deletions". I do think you'll be able to write your own driver here though.